# how to get x,y position of the selected Element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make the dialog which has the editor in it, want to to be either inline or stick to the element which it gets open to,but it is rendered through a `template.ejs` which looks like a modal right now

So,is there anyway i can get either X,Y position of the element or is there a better way to do this?

Here i get the element through `this.$el` and then add that into the editor,i either the editor to stick where the element is been opened in the editor.
`editor.js`

```
    render: function (options) {
        var that = this;
        // get x, y position from options of editElement and set top left of cke5-dialog
        this.options = $.extend(this.options, options);
        this.preRender();
        console.log(' Ckeditor5EditView rendered');
        let $el = this.$el;
        $el.show();
        let $editConatiner = $el.find('div.editable-container');
        let $toolConatiner = $el.find('div.toolbar-container');
        $editConatiner.html(this.options.htmlElm);
        $toolConatiner.html("");
        // $(this.options.editingElm).after(this.$el);
        // $(this.options.editingElm).hide();
        DecoupledEditor.create($editConatiner[0]).then(editor => {
            window.editor = editor;
            $toolConatiner[0].appendChild(editor.ui.view.toolbar.element);
            that.htmlEditor = editor;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error('There was a problem initializing the editor.', error);
        });
    },
```

```js
const sampleData = `
<p style="font:10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif;margin:0pt 0;text-align:justify;text-indent:0.25in;">
    In 2015, the Bangladesh subsidiary entered into agreements to rent office facilities under
<p>
`;
DecoupledEditor.create(sampleData)
  .then((editor) => {
    window.editor = editor;
    document
      .querySelector(".toolbar-container")
      .appendChild(editor.ui.view.toolbar.element);
    document
      .querySelector(".editable-container")
      .appendChild(editor.ui.view.editable.element);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(
      "There was a problem initializing the editor.",
      error
    );
  });
```

```css
.cke5-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  width: calc(72% - 4px);
  left: 25px;
  display: none;
}

.cke5-header {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 35px;
}

.cke5-button-pane {
  float: right;
}

.cke5-dialog-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cke5-editor-pane {
  width: 100%;
}

.cke5-dialog .toolbar-container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 3px;
}

.cke5-dialog .editable-container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid gray !important;
  background: #eee;
}

.cke5-dialog p {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.cke5-dialog .editable-container {
  padding: 10px!important;
  min-height: 130px;
  max-height: 600px;
}

.cke5-dialog .editable-container .document-editor__editable.ck-editor__editable {
  min-height: 21cm;
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
  border-radius: var(--ck-border-radius);
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p style="font:10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif;margin:0pt 0;text-align:justify;text-indent:0.25in;" xvid="774e1b176687ef278ec0984ac7cfb438">
    In 2015, the Bangladesh subsidiary entered into agreements to rent office facilities under
    <p>
      <div class='cke5-dialog-content'>
        <div class='cke5-header'>
          <div class="cke5-button-pane">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-cancel-html btn-xs cursor-pointer margin-right-5" data-rel="tooltip">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-update-html btn-xs cursor-pointer" data-rel="tooltip">
                    <i class="far fa-save"></i>
                </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='cke5-editor-pane'>
          <div class="toolbar-container"></div>
          <div class="editable-container"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document@30.0.0/build/ckeditor.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</body>
```

**#Update**: S i want to get the x,y position of the element on which i open the editor , i get that element through `$(this.options.editingElm)` so after getting the coordinates of that i want the editor to be in it.

Comment: @mplungjan added

Comment: So the question is, how to position `.cke5-dialog-content` next to where it was invoked?

Comment: @mplungjan yea, right now it doesn't stick and if i scroll the dialog goes with it, so first i thought of getting x,y position of the element(where it invoked) and make it stick there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can move the .cke5-dialog

be careful the editor does not overlay the other checkbox - you do not have borders so it is not obvious

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fnthmy2u/

```
const $editor = $(".cke5-dialog");
$(".text").on("contextmenu", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $editor.hide()
  $editor.css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
  $editor.show()
})
```